# Is building tor with Portable Native Client a sensible thing to do?

Tags: build

I was able to build tor using the PNaCl toolchain by removing `-z relro -z now` from the make file and compiling with `make CC=<pnacl clang binary>`.  Everything run by `make test` passes, and the resulting binary seems to function as normal.  I was a bit surprised at how easy it was.

Is this a sensible thing to do?  It seems like it would reduce the risk from any remote execution vulnerability tor might have.